# How to retrieve image from fire base

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question that how to get the image from a real-time database. In my code, I want to get the data from the database ( one is text form, one is image form ) and insert them in the recycler view. I get the reference from the internet and find these codes to realise my function. However, after inserting it, it still cannot be shown because my image is in string form but I cannot find any solution to solve it. Can somebody help me? Maybe the main problem is I do not know how to insert the URL of the real-time database.

Problem faced :

```html
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at com.example.assignment_mad.NotificationAdapter$MyViewHolder.<init>(Notificatiion_Adapter.kt:118)
        at com.example.assignment_mad.NotificationAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(Notificatiion_Adapter.kt:85)
        at com.example.assignment_mad.NotificationAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(Notificatiion_Adapter.kt:63)
```

Main code :

```html
package com.example.assignment_mad

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.example.assignment_mad.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.assignment_mad.databinding.FragmentNotificationBinding
import com.example.assignment_mad.databinding.FragmentSearchPageBinding
import com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_notification_.*


class Notification_Fragment : Fragment( ) {

    val database=Firebase.database
    val myRef=database.getReference("message")

    private var _binding:FragmentNotificationBinding?=null
    private val binding get()=_binding!!

    private lateinit var dbref: DatabaseReference

    private lateinit var newRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var newArrayList: ArrayList<Company>
    private lateinit var tempArrayList: ArrayList<Company>
    lateinit var imageId:Array<Int>
    lateinit var heading:Array<String>
    lateinit var news:Array<String>

    private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
    private var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.MyViewHolder>? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        var views =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification_, container, false)
        newRecyclerView=views.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

        newArrayList= arrayListOf<Company>()
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return views



    }

    override fun onViewCreated(itemView: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onViewCreated(itemView, savedInstanceState)


        adapter=NotificationAdapter(newArrayList)

        getUserdata()

    }


    private fun getUserdata() {
        dbref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://recyclerview-e3e96-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/").getReference("Notification")
        dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for (companySnapshot in snapshot.children){
                        val company=companySnapshot.getValue(Company::class.java)
                        newArrayList.add(company!!)
                    }
                    adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
            }

        })

        newRecyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        newRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        newRecyclerView.adapter=adapter
    }


}
```

The recyclerview adapter :

```html
package com.example.assignment_mad

import android.provider.Settings.System.getString
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.dropdown_item.view.*

class NotificationAdapter(private val companysList:ArrayList<Company>):RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false)

        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem=companysList[position]
        holder.titleImage.text=currentItem.titleImage
        //holder.titleImage.setImageResource(currentItem.titleImage)
        holder.tvHeading.text=currentItem.heading
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return companysList.size
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        //original 
        //val titleImage:ShapeableImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_image)
        val titleImage: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_image)
        val tvHeading: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeading)

    }

}
```

the xml file and list_item xml :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".Notification_Fragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item"/>

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

</FrameLayout>


------------------------------------------------------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/title_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/RoundCorner"
        android:src="@drawable/company_logo_1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="Candidate Biden Called Saudi Arable a Pareft eaft."
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/title_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_image"
        android:background="@color/underline"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The realtime firebase resource :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLhtu.png)

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you are seeing is because you define a `ShapeableImageView` in xml with id title_image, but you are casting it to a `TextView` in this line:

```
val titleImage: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_image)
```

Once you resolve this, consider using an image loading library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load the image URL you get from the Realtime Database into your ImageView.